# Color each section in a stacked bar plot differently

Tags: matlab, plot, visualization, data-visualization, matlab-figure

I have a stacked bar plot below:-

[image]

This was generated using:

```
b = barh(1:3,rand(3,2),'stacked');
```

Now i have a 3x2 cell `C` each cell element is a 1x3 RGB array.

```
C = cell(3,2);
for i = 1:3
  for j = 1:2
    C{i,j} = rand(1,3);
  end
end
```

There are 6 boxes in the figure and 6 corresponding colors. I want to fill these specified colors in the box. I thought using this method:

```
b(1).Parent.Parent.Colormap = C;
```

... but it did not work.

Can someone suggest how to draw custom stacked bar plots with the ability to control color of each bar segment? I don't think a tweaking of MATALB's `bar` command will help.

Comment: If you are trying to color each bar separately, perhaps `bar` graphs are not what you are looking for in the first place.

Comment: Tip: open up the [plot-tools](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/plotting-tools--interactive-plotting.html) to see what's actually happening, edit things by hand, and then take a look at the code that Matlab uses [(in the figure window, `file>generate M-file`)].

Comment: Which MATLAB version are you using? If done using `barh`, looks like it would require some reverse engineering of the `matlab.graphics.primitive.world.Quadrilateral` class....

Comment: @Dev-iL I am using MATLAB Version: 9.2.0.556344 (R2017a). Could you point to a source that does that?

Comment: @crazyGamer I agree! Any tip how to design custom stacked bar plots from scratch in matlab?

Comment: Please don't add answers as edits to the question. If you have a solution of your own, you can post it separately as an answer.

Comment: You may also want to look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45571774/2627163

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to duplicate and manipulate the graphics objects returned by the [`bar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html) (or `barh`) function

`bar(y, 'stacked')` returns one Bar graphics object for every column in `y`. The graphics objects have `XData` and `YData` fields which control the position and size of the bar sections. Since all sections from the same column share the graphics objects, you cannot manipulate the colors independantly.

For example, if `y` is a 2x3 matrix, `bar` returns 3 graphics objects. Each objects has:

- `XData`, a 1x2 vector containing bar indices
- `YData`, a 1x2 vector with each element being the height of the section.
- `FaceColor`, the color shared by all these sections

My code replicates these graphics objects, so that instead of 3 graphics objects with 1x2 `XData` and `YData` fields, you have 6 graphics objects with 1x1 `XData` and `YData`fields, each with a unique `FaceColor`.

Start off with a normal `bar` or `barh` graph

```
figure;
n_bars = 2;
n_sections = 3;

%Initialize the bar graph with default coloring
b = bar(rand(n_bars, n_sections), 'stacked');
```

Now, make a new figure to hold the plot with the manipulated colors

```
%Make new figure with new color scheme
f = figure;
a = axes('Parent', f);

%Colors
C = rand(6, 3);
```

For each graphics object from the original, make two copies.

```
for jj = 1:n_sections
  %Duplicate the bar graphics object results 
  section1 = copyobj(b(jj), a);
  section2 = copyobj(b(jj), a);

  % Remove one of the bars from each section
  section1.YData(1) = 0;
  section2.YData(2) = 0;

  %Change the color
  section1.FaceColor = C(sub2ind([n_bars, n_sections], 1, jj), :);
  section2.FaceColor = C(sub2ind([n_bars, n_sections], 2, jj), :);
end
```

Before and After!

[image: Default bar plot]
[image: Modified bar plot]

Comment: `jj` will range from 1.

Comment: @user_1_1_1 whoops, that's a debugging artifact

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to create a separate chart for each data row, otherwise we are unable to get single bar object handle.

```
ydata = rand(3,2); cdata={'r','g'; 'b','y';'c','k';'g','b'};
numplots = size(ydata,1);
h=zeros(numplots,2);
figure, hold on
for k=1:numplots,
    h(k,:) = barh(nan(size(ydata)),'stacked');
    set(h(k,1),'FaceColor',cdata{k,1});
    set(h(k,2),'FaceColor',cdata{k,2});
    tmp_ydata = get(h(k,1),'YData');
    tmp_ydata(k) = ydata(k,1); 
    set(h(k,1),'YData',tmp_ydata);
    tmp_ydata = get(h(k,2),'YData');
    tmp_ydata(k) = ydata(k,2);
    set(h(k,2),'YData',tmp_ydata);
end
hold off
```

For details please see post "Highlighting Parts of Charts" by 
[Mike on MATLAB Graphics](https://blogs.mathworks.com/graphics/2014/11/11/highlighting-parts-of-charts/)

Answer (score 1):

Based on Cecilia's answer here is a more general solution.

```
n_bars = 3;
n_sections = 4;
b = barh(rand(n_bars, n_sections), 'stacked');

f = figure;
a = axes('Parent', f);
C = rand(n_bars*n_sections, 3);
for jj = 1:n_sections
    for ii=1:n_bars
        section=copyobj(b(jj), a);
        dummy=1:n_bars;
        dummy(dummy==ii)=[];
        section.YData(dummy) = 0;
        section.FaceColor = C(sub2ind([n_bars, n_sections], ii, jj), :);
    end
end
```

For any values of `n_bars` and `n_sections`, this will work. If someone can suggest vectorized or more efficient implementation, please do.