# Matlab: bar No public property CData exists

Tags: matlab, colors, matlab-figure

The Matlab example code cannot run in Matlab 2017a (Linux 64bits):
https://cn.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html

```
b = bar(rand(10,1));
b.FaceColor = 'flat';
b.CData(2,:) = [.5 0 .5];
```

It can not color the specific bar and warns as:

> No public property CData exists for class matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Bar.

I don't know it is a specific feature merely for Matlab 2017b?

This code is only to color the specific bar. In Matlab 2012a, it can be easily done by:

```
bh=bar(MyStem); h=get(bh, 'children');
shading flat;  set(h,'FaceVertexCData',MyColor);
```

I cannot understand why Matlab 2017 removes this feature.

Comment: `CData` is a new property of 2017b. If you want to change the color of one bar only, there are here some good ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45568120/matlab-bars-changing-the-color-of-the-bar-and-the-space-between-bars-and-axes

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer and it is of embarrassment before Matlab 2017b that neither  has CData nor `get(barHandle, 'children')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the `CData` property, I wrote already in the comment.
Anyway, another workaround that I think can be more simple than those that been suggested, can be that:

```
x=rand(1,10);
b=bar([x;zeros(1,length(x))]);
xlim([0.5 1.5])
set(b,'FaceColor','r')
set(b(2),'FaceColor','b')
```

[image]

If you want to number the bars as in a regular bar graph, you can add this:

```
set(gca,'XTick',0.5+[b.XOffset])
set(gca,'XTicklabels',1:length(x))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you are looking for like this:

```
b = bar([rand(1,3);nan(1,3)],'b');
b(2).FaceColor = 'r';
```

You can also achieve this by calling the bar function multiple times with different values (which is a practice that you may need to use sometimes):

```
A = [1,2,3,4,1,3,2];

bar([1],A(1),'FaceColor','r');
bar([2:4],A(2:4),'FaceColor','g');
bar([5:7],A(5:7),'FaceColor','b');
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Certainly this is a workaround, but obviously  it is it is a VERY BAD experience before Matlab 2017b.  In a normal Matlab-style, it should be like `bar([2:4],A(2:4),'FaceColor', [1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1]);`, but this time I am really disappointed!!

Comment: What disappoints you exactly? If you have to release your work and ensure it runs on different matlab versions, you can always do a version check...

Comment: Ah ok I understand, well, you can summarize your changes into a loop for very huge graphs, for example.

Comment: Yes! Matlab should be ALWAYS a friendly tool.   : )